# Possible bug in /search/advanced API, has_more: false

Tags: bug, api

If I run this request:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#page=1&pagesize=10&todate=1479745525&order=desc&sort=creation&q=is&tagged=kentico&filter=!9YdnSIN18&site=stackoverflow&run=true

I get some results (not important what) and at the end `"has_more": false`. -> This is unexpected behavior as I know there are more data.

If I modify the request by changing `page` parameter to `2`, I get the second page of results and `has_more` is suddenly `true`. -> Correct

In other words, all requests except the first one return expected data.

I think it has something to do with `todate` parameter. If I remove it, it all works fine beginning with the first request (page).

Do you agree it's a bug or have I overlooked something?

Comment: If you switch the order to asc it also works ...

Comment: Yup, but that's not what I need :)

Comment: Make sure your todate is on the midnight of the next day. http://stackapps.com/a/6172/18722

Comment: Your query is also giving questions created after the `todate` (which is really a unix date+time).  There are related unresolved bugs, IIRC.

Comment: @rene Thanks but I need the today field to be set to this exact value.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Thx, perhaps I could use min, max parameters in combination whit sort=creation.

Comment: @rene, at least doing [that "fixes" the `has_more` bug](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#page=1&pagesize=10&todate=2016-12-01&order=desc&sort=creation&q=is&tagged=kentico&filter=!9YdnSIN18&site=stackoverflow&run=true).  Other bug is masked by the datetime chosen.

Comment: Rocky, yes setting `max` to the same as `todate` [does seem to work around the wrong results bug](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#page=1&pagesize=10&todate=1479745525&order=desc&max=1479745525&sort=creation&q=is&tagged=kentico&filter=!9YdnSIN18&site=stackoverflow&run=true).  Alas, the `has_more` bug remains.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now :(

Comment: Funny thing, if you change sort to activity it seems to work fine...